# Como obtener diagrama de fase de una FFT en MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Verán, tengo un vector en matlab que acumula los voltajes obtenidos en el tiempo. Luego, este vector le saco la fft y obtengo otro vector con los valores de voltaje versus frecuencia.

Mi pregunta es: ¿qué comando me permitiría coger este vector de fft y sacar otro vector que contenga la fase vs frecuencia?

Código:

```matlab
fy=fft(v1(1:i));
```

Conozco la función `bode` pero hasta donde conozco y he buscado sirve cuando tienes la función descrita en términos de `´s´`.

Comment: Qué sería `i`? Cómo la estás graficando?

Answer (score 0):

Para lo que necesitas existe la función [angle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/angle.html). De acuerdo al ejemplo en esa página:

```
y = fft(x); 
ys = fftshift(y);
th = 1e-6; 
ys(abs(ys) < th) = 0; 
phs = angle(ys);
```

Con ese código obtendrías la fase de los elementos del vector `ys` cuya magnitud sea mayor a `th`. Esto evita calcular la fase de elementos muy pequeños que darían como resultado fases erróneas debido a errores numéricos.

Comment: Ok. Igual estoy en el móvil y recién veo que la pregunta es de 2016. No entiendo porqué me aparece como relevante. Ahora edito y agrego el ejemplo.